# Ngrx unit test effects

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have strange error on unit test ngrx effects, here is my example

```
export const noop = (): any => null;
export const obsNoop = () => of({});
export const mockObs = () => {
  return {
    subscribe: () => { }
  };
};

const initialState: Tutorial[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Google', url: 'google.com' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Yahoo', url: 'yahoo.com' },
];

class MockTutorialsService {
  getAll = obsNoop;
}

fdescribe('AppEffects', () => {
  let actions$: Observable<any>;
  let effects: TutorialEffects;
  let store: MockStore<AppState>;
  let httpService: TutorialsService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        TutorialEffects,
        provideMockActions(() => actions$),
        provideMockStore({ initialState }),
        { provide: TutorialsService, useClass: MockTutorialsService }
      ],
    });

    effects = TestBed.inject(TutorialEffects);
    store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
    httpService = TestBed.inject(TutorialsService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(effects).toBeTruthy();
  });

  // Testing API interaction
  describe('onFetchUsers$', () => {
    it('should fire if users is null', (done) => {
      const spy = spyOn(httpService, 'getAll').and.callThrough();
      actions$ = of(TutorialActions.GET_TUTORIALS);
      effects.loadTutorials$.subscribe((res) => {
        expect(res).toEqual(new TutorialActions.SuccesGetTutorials(res));
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        done();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

The error I got is related to karma likeError:
**Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) this**

Does anybody knows where I have gone wrong?

Here is effects

```
Injectable()
export class TutorialEffects {
  loadTutorials$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.action$.pipe(
      ofType(TutorialActions.GET_TUTORIALS),
      switchMap(() =>
        this.tutorialService.getAll().pipe(
          map((tutorial: Tutorial[]) => new TutorialActions.SuccesGetTutorials(tutorial)),
          catchError((error) => of(error))
        )
      )
    )
  );


  constructor(private action$: Actions, private tutorialService: TutorialsService) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the effect, I am taking guesses but the issue is that the test is not going inside of the `effects.loadTutorials$.subscribe` line and calling `done` within `5 seconds`.

```
effects.loadTutorials$.subscribe((res) => {
        console.log('!! Inside of the subscribe !!'); // make sure you see this log
        expect(res).toEqual(new TutorialActions.SuccesGetTutorials(res));
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        done();
      });
```

I think a culprit is the `and.callThrough()`. I think you should return a fake response.

```
const spy = spyOn(httpService, 'getAll').and.returnValue(of({/* mock response */ });
```

====== Edit ======

```
  loadTutorials$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.action$.pipe(
      ofType(TutorialActions.GET_TUTORIALS),
      switchMap(() => {
        console.log('!! Inside of switchMap !!');
        return this.tutorialService.getAll().pipe(
          map((tutorial: Tutorial[]) => { 
           console.log('!! Inside of map !!');
           return new TutorialActions.SuccesGetTutorials(tutorial); }),
          catchError((error) => of(error))
        )
      })
    )
  );
```

Comment: I have added effects, also i got nothing with console.log

Comment: Did you change the `spy` as well? If you changed the `spy`, everything else seems to look good for me.

Comment: Yes I changed and spy

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to help you other than maybe add those logs in the edit I have just made and see which one is not logging and determine why they are not logging.

Comment: It never geets in subscribe, not even one console.log is fired

Comment: Then I think the actions are not provided correctly if one console.log is not fired. I am not sure what it can be, sorry.

Comment: Can you add the TutorialActions.GET_TUTORIALS definition to your question? Is it just a string or an action creator?